# Rails conditions on joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, conditional-statements

I have tables a,b. Associated classes

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :b
end

class B <ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

b has integer field c.

I want to retrieve all records of A that have a B which has c< 5.

I've tried

```
A.find(:conditions => (B.c < 5) )
```

but I get complaints "undefined member c".

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A.joins(:b).where("b.c < 5")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use find.
Go ahead with "where"

```
A.joins(:b).where("b.c < 5")

A.b.where("c < 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 A.b.where("c < 5")
```

dont use the find contions, it is decremented with rails 3